# Clonezilla keeps dropping cloning speed when cloning on an ethernet connection

Tags: linux, networking, backup, clonezilla

So after getting a new laptop, I've turned my old laptop into a small server (installed `Linux Mint` on it because I still want to control using a GUI (not the best distro for server i know)), and with over 200GB of free storage, I've decided to turn the server into a backup server.

Now, the way I've setup my computer with the server is that:

- My main computer would be connected to the server using an Ethernet cable.
- On the server, I've set the wired connection to `Shared to other computers`, which would allow my main computer to have full access to the server (ssh, data, etc.).

And being an Ethernet connection, it should reach around 1 Gbits/sec (which it did when I tested it using `iperf`):

```
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr  Cwnd
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   116 MBytes   974 Mbits/sec    0   1.06 MBytes       
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   112 MBytes   942 Mbits/sec    0   1.06 MBytes       
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   112 MBytes   941 Mbits/sec    0   1.06 MBytes       
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   112 MBytes   941 Mbits/sec    0   1.06 MBytes       
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   112 MBytes   942 Mbits/sec    0   1.06 MBytes       
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   112 MBytes   941 Mbits/sec    0   1.06 MBytes       
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec   112 MBytes   941 Mbits/sec    0   1.06 MBytes       
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   112 MBytes   941 Mbits/sec    0   1.06 MBytes       
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   112 MBytes   940 Mbits/sec    0   1.06 MBytes       
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   112 MBytes   940 Mbits/sec    0   1.06 MBytes       
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.10 GBytes   944 Mbits/sec    0             sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.10 GBytes   941 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

So I tried to make a backup of my main computer to my server using Clonezilla (a tool I've been using to create backup for quite sometimes). And when I configured it to use the remote server to store the backup, it seems to work with no problem. Clonezilla was able to detect the server, authenticate and connect to it, so everything looks smooth... until it actually started to back up the data.

At first, the speed was pretty high (7.5 GB / minutes), but when it started dropping dramatically (down to like 600 MB / minutes) and even sometimes to 200 MB / minutes. And I was hoping that maybe it will readjust and bring the speed back up, but nope, it didn't. It kept fluctuating at around 600 MB / minutes.

I don't know if there's a setting in Clonezilla or in the servers that I need to adjust so it would use the highest speed possible, or a bug or an issue which cause the speed to drop when transferring over Ethernet in Clonezilla or ssh.

I'd really like to hear your thoughts and ideas on how I could potentially fix this problem (except ideas like: "Use other back up software").

Answer (score 1):

If your ethernet NICs at both ends support 1 Gbps connection speed, then a transfer rate of 600 MB/s is actually more than what you should be getting. Remember that Gbps != GB/s. The transfer in Mbps and MB/s should be factor of around 1/8th and that is what iperf is telling you as well, somewhere around 128 MB/s would be the average you can expect on the line. As for the initial speeds, those are going to be high as the program has yet to start transferring enough data for its speed estimate to be accurate. Those are mostly meaningless.